# INSERT INTO SQL DATEADD Yesterday

Tags: mysql, dateadd

I want to use PHP and MySQL to INSERT the the day of Yesterday. So my idea was:

```
INTO chartValues SET timestamp='1353369600', `datetime`=DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())
```

But its not working:

> 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INTO chartValues SET timestamp='1353369600',
>   `datetime`=DATEADD(d,-1,GETDATE())' at line 1

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DATEADD` and `GETDATE()` are T-SQL functions used in SQL Server.

You want to use `DATE_ADD()` or `DATE_SUB()` with `NOW()`

```
INSERT INTO chartValues SET timestamp='1353369600', `datetime`= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)
```

[Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-add)

> `DATE_SUB(date, INTERVAL expr unit)`

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should use `NOW()` in MySql, instead of `getdate()`. See [Mysql Date and Time Functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html).

Answer (score 0):

Date_add()  not dateadd()
now() not getdate()

the link at the bottom is a good reference to mysql programming I recommend it.

so `datetime` = date_add(d,-1,now())

http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_date_add.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this in php:

```
date("F j, Y", time() - 60 * 60 * 24);
```

depending the datatype in your database you can change the "F j, Y" with the format that you need.

An in mysql something like this:

```
CAST(NOW() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AS DATE).
```